# What does "ps -ef|grep processname" mean?

Tags: command-line, grep, ps

I want to know exactly what this particular command

```
ps -ef|grep processname
```

means and how it works. I know that this should be associated with `processname` which we want to search for, but I don't get the prefix part; what do `-ef` and `|`(pipe) do and how does `-ef|grep` as a whole work. Upon googling a bit I found `grep` is used for searching purposes, but I would love a simple explanation of how this command setting works.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`-e` and `-f` are options to the `ps` command, and pipes take the output of one command and pass it as the input to another. Here is a full breakdown of this command:

- `ps` - list processes
- `-e` - show all processes, not just those belonging to the user
- `-f` - show processes in full format (more detailed than default)
- `command 1 | command 2` - pass output of command 1 as input to command 2
- `grep` find lines containing a pattern
- `processname` - the pattern for `grep` to search for in the output of `ps -ef`

So altogether

```
ps -ef | grep processname
```

means: look for lines containing `processname` in a detailed overview/snapshot of all current processes, and display those lines